# HTTP Request packet getting corrupted

Tags: java, http, servlets

When I received an HTTP request of smaller length it's fine, but when receiving long packet getting corrupted. I took a trace through wire shark and I printed packet in hex value in JAVA console. Some additional values are showing in that printing. Why?
How can I solve it?

Is there anything wrong with conversion of HTTP request to Hex.

Following code is used to convert String to Hex.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

InputStream responseData = request.getInputStream();

byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
int bytesRead = 0;
while ((bytesRead = responseData.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    sb=baos.toString();
    str = baos.toString();
    sb.append(str);
    sb = new String(baos.toByteArray(),UTF8);
}

baos.close(); // connection.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't convert the read bytes to a `String` until all your input is read because a fraction of the input might be invalid UTF-8 encoded data.

Also don't use `ByteArrayOutputStream.toString()` because it uses the platform's default character set to decode bytes to characters (`String`) which is indeterministic. Instead use `ByteArrayOutputStream.toString(String charsetName)` and specify the encoding.

Also you should use `ServletRequest.getCharacterEncoding()` to detect encoding and revert to `UTF-8` for example if it is unknown.

First read all input, and then convert it to a `String`:

```
String encoding = ServletRequest.getCharacterEncoding();
if (encoding == null)
    encoding = "UTF-8";

// First read all input data    
while ((bytesRead = responseData.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}

// We have all input, now convert it to String:
String text = baos.toString(encoding);
```

### Better Alternative

Since you convert the binary input to a `String`, you should use `ServletRequest.getReader()` instead of reading binary data using `ServletRequest.getInputStream()` and converting it to `String` manually.

E.g. reading all lines:

```
BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    // Process line, here I just append it to a StringBuilder
    sb.append(line);
    // If you want to preserve newline characters, keep the next line:
    sb.append('\n');
}
```